# Displaying foreign key on datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

Lets say I have two tables in database, Table1 and Table2. Relationship is one to many from table2 to table1. I would like to show all data from Table1 and not all columns from Table2 on GUI. Foreign key from table2 is column in Table1:

```
Table2 table2;
```

I am trying to display data from Table1 and  some columns from Table2+foreign key. My problem is how to display foreign key, here is part of code:

```
List<Table1> list = new List<Table1>();
Table t2 = new Table2();
t2.prop1 = done using OledBReader;
t2.prop2 = ...;
t2.prop3 = ...;


Table1 t1 = new Table1();
t1.prop1 = ...;
t1.prop2 = ...;
*t1.Table2 = t2;*

list.Add(t1);
```

Two properties of Table2 are name and surname so I am overriding toString(), so that one column will be Name Surname. Foreign key is ID, but I dont know how to display It as a column (I dont want to include it in override method). My problem is that instead of that ID which is foreign key, I have property which is entire object of class Table2, and in Table2 I have to override name and surname, so I dont know where to include this ID, so I will have ID column at the end?

I hope this explanation is helpful.

Comment: Foreign key table 2 is primary key of table 1 right ? If you show all columns from table 1, then its present there. Then what are you trying to achive?

Comment: @Krishna got it now. Well, I didnt have because instead of foreign key property, I had entire object as property, but I added both entire object as property(where tostring() is overriden and I am getting name and surname as one column), and ID also as property in Table1(so now I am finally displaying that column too). Thanks for your effort to help!